# Should I use tok2vec before ner in spacy?

Tags: nlp, model, pipeline, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm currently training a model for named entity recognition and I could not find out how the pipeline in spacy should be structured in order to achieve better results. Does it make sense to use tok2vec before the ner component?

Answer (score 2):

The NER component requires a tok2vec (or Transformers) component as a source of features, and will not work without it.

For more details about pipeline structure and feature sources, [this section of the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers#embedding-layers) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have created a pipeline consisting just the "ner" component in spacy and it is still working fine. Do you know what the reason is?

Comment: That's possible if the tok2vec is embedded, which is referred to as the "independent" model in the linked docs. You can get it by not using listeners or by using `replace_listeners` when sourcing a component, for example. The tok2vec must still exist.